# request-promise cannot be webpacked

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, webpack

So I'm attemping to use request-promise in client-side, and trying to pack with webpack, but because of some file modules `fs`, it cannot be packed to client-side. Has anyone stumble upon this same problem and solved ?

This is the compilation output

```
ERROR in ./~/request-promise/~/request/lib/har.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/lib
 @ ./~/request-promise/~/request/lib/har.js 3:9-22

ERROR in ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'net' in /node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/node_modules/forever-agent
 @ ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/forever-agent/index.js 6:10-24

ERROR in ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'tls' in /node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/node_modules/forever-agent
 @ ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/forever-agent/index.js 7:10-24

ERROR in ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'net' in /node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/node_modules/tough-cookie/lib
 @ ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js 32:10-24

ERROR in ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/tough-cookie/package.json
Module parse failed: /node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/node_modules/tough-cookie/package.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "author": {
|     "name": "Jeremy Stashewsky",
|     "email": "jstashewsky@salesforce.com"
 @ ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js 38:14-40

ERROR in ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'net' in /node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent
 @ ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/tunnel-agent/index.js 3:10-24

ERROR in ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'tls' in /node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent
 @ ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/tunnel-agent/index.js 4:10-24

ERROR in ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/mime-types/~/mime-db/db.json
Module parse failed: /node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/node_modules/mime-types/node_modules/mime-db/db.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "application/1d-interleaved-parityfec": {
|     "source": "iana"
|   },
 @ ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/mime-types/~/mime-db/index.js 11:17-37

ERROR in ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/cache.json
Module parse failed: /node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/node_modules/har-validator/lib/schemas/cache.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "properties": {
|     "beforeRequest": {
|       "$ref": "#cacheEntry"
 @ ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 4:9-32

ERROR in ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/cacheEntry.json
Module parse failed: /node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/node_modules/har-validator/lib/schemas/cacheEntry.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "oneOf": [{
|     "type": "object",
|     "optional": true,
 @ ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 5:14-42

ERROR in ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/har.json
Module parse failed: /node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/node_modules/har-validator/lib/schemas/har.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "required": [
|     "log"
 @ ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 10:7-28

ERROR in ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/creator.json
Module parse failed: /node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/node_modules/har-validator/lib/schemas/creator.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "required": [
|     "name",
 @ ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 8:11-36

ERROR in ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/content.json
Module parse failed: /node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/node_modules/har-validator/lib/schemas/content.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "required": [
|     "size",
 @ ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 6:11-36

ERROR in ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/cookie.json
Module parse failed: /node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/node_modules/har-validator/lib/schemas/cookie.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "required": [
|     "name",
 @ ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 7:10-34

ERROR in ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/page.json
Module parse failed: /node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/node_modules/har-validator/lib/schemas/page.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "optional": true,
|   "required": [
 @ ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 12:8-30

ERROR in ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/pageTimings.json
Module parse failed: /node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/node_modules/har-validator/lib/schemas/pageTimings.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "properties": {
|     "onContentLoad": {
 @ ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 13:15-44

ERROR in ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/request.json
Module parse failed: /node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/node_modules/har-validator/lib/schemas/request.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "required": [
|     "method",
 @ ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 16:11-36

ERROR in ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/entry.json
Module parse failed: /node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/node_modules/har-validator/lib/schemas/entry.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "optional": true,
|   "required": [
 @ ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 9:9-32

ERROR in ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/log.json
Module parse failed: /node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/node_modules/har-validator/lib/schemas/log.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "required": [
|     "version",
 @ ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 11:7-28

ERROR in ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/record.json
Module parse failed: /node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/node_modules/har-validator/lib/schemas/record.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "required": [
|     "name",
 @ ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 15:10-34

ERROR in ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/postData.json
Module parse failed: /node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/node_modules/har-validator/lib/schemas/postData.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "optional": true,
|   "required": [
 @ ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 14:12-38

ERROR in ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/timings.json
Module parse failed: /node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/node_modules/har-validator/lib/schemas/timings.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "required": [
|     "send",
|     "wait",
 @ ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 18:11-36

ERROR in ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/response.json
Module parse failed: /node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/node_modules/har-validator/lib/schemas/response.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "required": [
|     "status",
 @ ./~/request-promise/~/request/~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 17:12-38
```

Comment: Request-promise is a server side library, that uses server-side native tools in order to make HTTP requests. You cannot package it for the front end.

Comment: thanks Yuri, I finally decided to go plain vanillajs.